# Can I connect one service account to multiple namespaces in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubectl, rbac, kubernetes-namespace

I have couple of namespaces - assume `NS1` and `NS2`. I have serviceaccounts created in those - `sa1` in `NS1` and `sa2` in `NS2`. I have created roles and rolebindings for `sa1` to do stuff within `NS1` and `sa2` within `NS2`.
What I want is give `sa1` certain access within `NS2` (say only Pod Reader role).

I am wondering if that's possible or not?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can simply reference a ServiceAccount from another namespace in the RoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
  namespace: ns2
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-reader-from-ns1
  namespace: ns2
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ns1-service-account
  namespace: ns1
```

Comment: can we apply same concept to make communication between **Service** [NodePort in ns1] and **Ingress** [Aws-alb-ingress-controller in ns2] i.e; across 2 different namespace?

Comment: @AshishKumar here you can use a service of type ExternalName.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP can service of type ExternalName distribute the traffic among multiple pods under same label specified.

Comment: @Ashish a service of type external name is nothing more, than a CNAME record in the cluster dns. The balancing is then done by the service it is pointing to.

Comment: Detail: `kind: Role` in the `roleRef section` will be removed by k8s. You could just use `namespace: n2` in this section.

Comment: There is also a very good and clear article about the topic: https://octopus.com/blog/k8s-rbac-roles-and-bindings This finally helped me to understand the relationship between service accounts, roles, role bindings, cluster roles and cluster role bindings.